# Phonegap vs Android Native SDK for supporting multiple languages

Tags: android, cordova, localization, internationalization

I want to parse a planet feed which has multiple rss that supports multiple languages like Spanish, German, etc

My question is should I go with phonegap or native android sdk. I am not sure which one would be better that can support this requirement.

Comment: use google for a while boss..!!

Comment: hey I did Google it, And have already considered the answers given below, it was just that I wanted an answer specific to localization,

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your skill set. If you have to learn javascript and java it doesn't matter. Pick one and learn how to do it. If you already know javascript or java, pick the one you know better/like the most and go for it.

The native sdk offers localization : [see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). Using phonegap, you'll have to define your own javascript localisation methods. Which is not so complicated, I have done it before and I'm not expert in javascript.

You also have to consider other things like:

- Is your app android only or you'll support other platforms?
- How "heavy" is your app? Does it render heavy graphics or has fancy animations? In my epxerience phonegap gets a bit laggy on
  those.

Search the differences, pros and cons of doing both. [To help you get started.](http://bit.ly/ZmZYiM)